# Make itemize look like dirtree

Tags: itemize, dirtree

I have the following itemized list:

[image]

but I would like the indentation to be generated as this:

[image]

I have tried what is in [this link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282987/present-a-list-as-a-tree) as follows

```
\dirtree{%
.1 Gas ideal (partículas idénticas que no interactúan, i.e. la energía no tiene términos cruzados).
.2 Fermiones.
.3 Límite de gas no degenerado. Corresponde a temperaturas muy altas y densidades muy bajas, el resultado es el gas ideal clásico.
.3 Límite de gas degenerado. Es lo opuesto, temperaturas bajas y densidades altas. Aparece Pauli con su principio de exclusión. 
.4 Enanas blancas. 
.2 Bosones.
.3 Límite de gas no degenerado. Corresponde a temperaturas muy altas y densidades muy bajas, el resultado es el gas ideal clásico.
.4 Gas de fotones.
.4 Gas de fonones.
.3 Límite de gas degenerado. Básicamente es un condensado de Bose-Einstein. 
.4 Superfluidos.
.4 Superconductores.
.1 Otros temas que no sean gas ideal. No vimos nada, creo.
}
```

with no success. I get an error that says

> Use of \next doesn't match its definition.

Comment: Yes, I get the same error. Sorry I forgot to put it in the question. Now I have added it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you yourself have noticed, `dirtree` is not really the right tool for this purpose. One possibility is to use TikZ's `forest`, as Alan pointed out in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/420685/make-itemize-look-like-dirtree/420688?noredirect=1#comment1054158_420688). If you prefer the input structure of LaTeX lists, you could combine `enumitem` and TikZ to get something like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tikz}

\makeatletter
    \newlist{treelist}{itemize}{5}
    \setlist[treelist]{label=\treelist@label}

    \tikzset{treelist line/.style={thick, line cap=round, rounded corners}}
    \def\treelist@label{%
        \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, baseline={([yshift=-.6ex] treelist-bullet-\the\enit@depth.center)}]
            \draw [treelist line] (0, 0) -- node (treelist-bullet-\the\enit@depth) {} ++(.5em, 0);
        \end{tikzpicture}%
        \ifnum\enit@depth>1
            \tikz[remember picture, overlay] \draw [treelist line] (treelist-bullet-\the\numexpr\enit@depth-1\relax.center) |- (treelist-bullet-\the\enit@depth.center);%
        \fi
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{treelist}
    \item
    Gas ideal (partículas idénticas que no interactúan, i.e.~la energía no tiene términos cruzados).
    \begin{treelist}
        \item
        Fermiones.
        \begin{treelist}
            \item
            Límite de gas no degenerado.
            Corresponde a temperaturas muy altas y densidades muy bajas, el resultado es el gas ideal clásico.

            \item
            Límite de gas degenerado.
            Es lo opuesto, temperaturas bajas y densidades altas.
            Aparece Pauli con su principio de exclusión. 
            \begin{treelist}
            \item
            Enanas blancas. 

            \end{treelist}

        \end{treelist}

        \item
        Bosones.
        \begin{treelist}
            \item
            Límite de gas no degenerado.
            Corresponde a temperaturas muy altas y densidades muy bajas, el resultado es el gas ideal clásico.
            \begin{treelist}
                \item
                Gas de fotones.

                \item
                Gas de fonones.

            \end{treelist}

            \item
            Límite de gas degenerado.
            Básicamente es un condensado de Bose-Einstein.
            \begin{treelist}
                \item
                Superfluidos.

                \item
                Superconductores.

            \end{treelist}

        \end{treelist}

    \end{treelist}

    \item
    Otros temas que no sean gas ideal. No vimos nada, creo.

\end{treelist}

\end{document}
```

[image: output from the code above]

The `5` in `\newlist{treelist}{itemize}{5}` sets the maximum list depth. If you need more than five levels, just increase this number. If you want to further customize the appearance of these lists, you should have a look at the documentations of [`enumitem`](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/enumitem/enumitem.pdf) and [TikZ](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

- You forgot the `%` after `\dirtree{` (as pointed out as required in the link you provided).
- Since you have dots in your list items, you will need to hide them as in

  ```
  .3 {Límite de gas degenerado. Básicamente es un condensado de Bose-Einstein}.
  ```

  Note that the last dot will not show up in your output, since it marks the end of the item.
- You Probably want to define `\renewcommand*\DTstyle{}` in order for the list not to be typeset using `\ttfamily`.

---

- Also, you should replace `i.e. la` by `i.e.~la` or one of the other possibilities that tell TeX that there is no end of sentence here. See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2229/is-a-period-after-an-abbreviation-the-same-as-an-end-of-sentence-period), for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It solved the problem about the compilation but now I see that dirtree is not the most appropriate way to do what I want. It generates an output as in the image on this URL: https://image.ibb.co/jv3QXx/imagen.png and not only changes the font style but also fails where I have indicated in red. Do you know any alternatives? Thank you anyway!

Comment: @user171780 In addition to @remco's comment, the same question you linked to has an alternative solution using `forest`, a TikZ based tree drawing package.

Comment: @user171780: See my second answer for another possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put a '%' immediately after the '\dirtree{'.  The link you provided has that '%', with a comment saying " This % is required"

Comment: See the answer below for the problem with the extra '.' you have in your nodes. According to the docs, a node is defined as ".<level><space><note text>.<space", so any '. ' within a node (like end of phrase) will end the current node, but it's not followed by the next node ('.<level>' combination like '.3') => error